# How to HTTP GET or POST with Matlab or Octave?

Tags: http, matlab, http-post, octave, http-get

In [Matlab Function Alphabetical Reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/funcalpha.html) I only found the following function:

- [web](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/web.html) - Open Web site or file in Web or Help browser

Isn't there a way of accessing a web resource without opening a browser?
Or how to close the browser?

I tried `web stackoverflow.com -browser` and it doesn't open the browser, but fiddler tells me that no web resource was fetched because of this command.

**Edit** Somehow Fiddler doesn't gets the Matlab http traffic, so I guess that the `web url -browser` command works for me, but I'd rather use the `urlread` command as suggested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[urlread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/urlread.html) might do the job. In case of proxy issues [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076564/calling-a-jax-ws-webservice-from-inside-matlab/4099942#4099942) might help as well.

Looking at the implementation you might see that The MathWorks is heavily relying on Java libraries.